# postgresql functional foreign keys

Tags: postgresql

Here is what I would like to do:

```
create table stuff
   (some_key  varchar primary key,
    some_data varchar)
;

create table obfuscated_stuff
   (some_key_sha1 varchar references digest(stuff (some_key), 'sha1'),
    other_data varchar)
;
```

In other words, I'd like to set up a foreign key to the other table based on a one way hash without having to put that hash in the original table.

This is a policy/regulatory requirement.  I can build the "obfuscated_stuff" table without the FK constraint, but I'd rather have it there.

It appears using a function in an FK constraint is not allowed.  I also can't do an FK to a view (which might have the function in it).  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Whats the ultimate goal. Could you not just hide an id and then join the tables in the background. Whats the purpose of the obfuscated stuff? Usually stuff like this is better done with permissions and good backend engineering.

Comment: The policy makers do not want us to join the two data sets explicitly.  We already have the relevant column level permissions locked down on the parent table.  The process which inserts data into child table needs a reference back to the row in the parent table.  I'd rather include a constraint which ensures the references are valid, if I can.

Comment: Do you know `some_key` when inserting `some_key_sha1` into the obfuscated child table?

Comment: No.  We only know the hash at that time.  That is part of the anonymization approach.  The jobs working with the data don't know which rows they are really working with, they don't need to.  They only need to know the values of a couple of columns, which are exposed through a view that also hides the source column key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the current [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) you can't do this. Only a column or group of column names allowed.

You are right, that you can not make FKs on views. This is true for materialized views too.

You can write a trigger on BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE of the referer column, that checks the referred indexed column. On violation, return NULL or exception. On the referred table's PK, you can even create an index with the hashed values.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't think of a trigger to enforce constraints.  I'll consider that.  Interesting idea.